# TIA Portal Openness - modify project library types

Tags: siemens, tia-portal

In TIA Portal Openness (API version 16, 17 or 18) - is there a way to edit library types? That is, to modify a library type and release the change as a new version?

Specifically, I wish to modify PLC User Defined Types (UDTs).

using Openness, I have managed to:

- Instantiate a library UDT type in a PLC
- Export it as XML (no library type information was included in the export)
- Modify the XML file
- Import the XML file, but only when the UDT type is not being edited

The PLC UDT is updated according to the changes in the XML file, but it is no longer linked to a library type.  However, I wish to make versioned changes as above.  Is this possible?  If yes, how?